# Is it possible to steal foreign app iCloud prefs?

Tags: objective-c, icloud

I store some preferences in iCloud with a help of `[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]`. Can foreign apps get data from my app cloud using my app cloudURL `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]` or using something else? If yes, how can I protect my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, every app works in its own sandbox and therefore it is not possible to get data from other (3rd party) apps - it doesn't matter whether they store their stuff in iCloud or on the device.

If you want to provide some data from one of your apps for other apps then you need to provide them on your own server so other apps can download what they need.

But of course the people owning the actual device can access all information stored on the device if they use programs on their computers that allow people to access iPhone's file system.